# How to get data from MS Access to listview VB6

Tags: listview, ms-access, vb6

I have data in listview VB6 like this.

[image: Listview in VB6]

and this is the coding for insert data to my listview from textbox "Receivedata"

```
Private Sub AddList_Click()  
Dim i As Long
Dim sLines() As String
Dim sValues() As String
Dim oItem As ListItem

sLines() = Split(receivedata.Text, vbCrLf)
For i = 0 To UBound(sLines)
   If sLines(i) > vbNullString Then ' skip for empty line
      sValues() = Split(sLines(i), ".")

      Set oItem = ListView1.ListItems.Add(, , sValues(0))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(1))
      Call oItem.ListSubItems.Add(, , sValues(2))
   End If
Next i
End Sub
```

and this is my database in ms access:

[image: database]

i want to get data "Product_Name" and "Price" from ms access by matching the barcode's data.

how to connect the ms access with VB6 and get thedata from ms access to my listview?
i builded connection from ADODC like this:

[image]

please help me..

Comment: Is the ReceiveData textbox just a temporary thing?  Do you mean that you want to import from the database instead?

Comment: ADO Data Control can be helpful for navigating a database recordset with bound controls on your form. But it looks like you want to import an entire table (or query) into a single list box. It would  be better to create a separate ADO connection in code, then submit a query and get a Recordset object. Loop through the recordset rows in a similar fashion as you loop through lines of your Receivedata textbox.  [Here is just one link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/using-ado-with-microsoft-visual-basic) to get you started, but the details are beyond posting here.

Comment: using the dot as field separator looks very ugly... 8-:(

Comment: @CPerkins data in receivedata is receiving from android data. i've succedd to separate 3 data to 3 coloum listview. now the problem is to get data "Product_name" and "Price" from database in accordance with the barcode data from listview in VB6

Comment: @deblocker that's data from my android :') but now the problem is to get data "Product_name" and "Price" from database in accordance with the barcode data from listview in VB6. can you help me, please?

Comment: Stack Overflow questions are not for general tutorial requests, nor for someone else to write the code.  I already gave you one hint to use other ADO objects instead of the ADO Data Control (ADODC).  If you insist on using the ADO Data Control, start with [this MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa231217.aspx), then do a web search for other tutorials on ADO controls.

Comment: @CPerkins thankyou for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible approach: once you have successfully connected to your database table, You may use the (almost forgotten) `Filter`property of the `ADODB.Recordset`.

Inside the loop of your received data, you should **restrict** the **price master data** of your product to just only the **one row** you need:

```
Adodc1.Recordset.Filter = "Barcode = '" & sValues(1) & "'"
```

Then, depending from your connection string, you may find the product name and price inside the Recordset Fields collection. For example:

```
ProductName = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Product_Name")
Price = Adodc1.Recordset.Fields("Price")
```

**Additional information:**

As your question is somewhat broader than just only the ADO Data Control, an additional discussion is required. I'm posting the discussion here, because it doesn't fit inside a comment.

You should think about the questions below and try to get an answer by yourself.

Premise: from the screenshot of your Products Table, it seems to me you have defined the autoincrement `Number`field as Primary Key.

**Q:** How can you be sure, when you apply the `Filter`, that there will be just only one row for each Barcode? Is there in your database table a constraint which can avoid such a scenario?

**Q:** What happened, and what action you should undertake if you find two rows with different prices?

Below are the Fields from the *Price List* table of a popular international ERP software:

- Product Code
- Customer Code
- Product Group
- Customer Group
- Currency Code
- Minimum Quantity
- Starting Date
- Ending Date
- Price (Local Currency)
- Price (Foreign Currency)
- Barcode

**Q:** what are the fields of the Primary Key?

**Q:** why isn't the field *Product Name* inside this table?

**Q:** Why isn't the field *Ending Date* in the Primary Key?

**Q:** How many Foreign Keys exists in the database, which are related to this *Price List* table?

**Q:** Why there is another Barcode field in the *Product* table, but doesn't contain the same data?

Happy learning!

Comment: me too, every day. please, take the discussion above seriously... once you get the answers to the _7 Price List easy questions_, you will be ready for the _7 Price List hard questions_  :)